# Requirment Analysis Communication

Tags: communication, requirements, meetings

Someday s ago we was discussing about the current project, and suddenly sir and my senior started talking about the new feature to add in the project , and i become lost :). i was not able to find how i should provide my input for the new feature.
So i want to know what things should be discussed for developing new feature in project and how we can contribute in requirement talk of new features.

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried user stories? They were made for capturing discussions like this.

Comment: @Martin: +1 user story is a great tool to define a feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to contribute in new features of your product, I highly suggest you to get some interest in the business.

You can do that by **asking questions**. Ask until your understand. If you are not sure, ask another question.

Try to talk with business people more often. Try to understand how your stuff is going to be used. How you are going to improve their life. Read magazine and articles of your industry. This process will certainly contribute in making you more aware of what you do.

I think this is one of the factor that makes the difference between a **just developer** and a **great developer**.

> Great developers ask lot of questions

Answer (score 2):

Are you new to the project? I can remember my first couple of months of out school. Honestly, the level of intelligence and knowledge I thought my co-developers had was intimidating. Fresh college grad v.s 15-20 year of experience can be a rather large gap. I felt like it took approximatively 3 year's before I was really on par with them. That is not to say I couldn't contribute earlier. I just felt like I was not an equal contributer until that point.

What I can suggest?

Listen to their discussions. Ask questions. Make them explain their thought processes or anything that you don't understand. The senior members of the team should be more than happy to mentor the more inexperienced developers. Read design documentation. Ask question about design documentation that you don't understand. Be an information sponge. The learning curve strait out of school can be daunting. Don't let that make you afraid. Eventually,  you start to see the larger picture.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a few basics that come to mind with most features:

- Significance - Why are we doing this?  Sometimes if one can get what the story is then there may be alternatives to explore.
- Priority - Is this something to be done ASAP and stop the world we are focusing this now and everyone will do their part to get this complete soon?
- Scope - How broad is the new feature?  Do they think it'll take a few years or a few hours to finish?  Are boundary conditions covered yet in the requirements,e.g. if someone tries to put in X as a number what should the system do?  This applies in a few dimensions as sometimes a small thing can become a big thing and a big thing can become a small thing depending on what is being asked.

I would suggest keeping notes at times when a feature is discussed just to keep an eye on what was discussed and possibly ask if someone could send a summary of what was agreed to be done as that can prevent miscommunication.